# Converting giant JavaScript feature collection of coordinates to GEE feature collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, coordinates, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-collection

I have a very large JavaScript feature collection (I think - will post a snippet below) and I want to display the vectors in Earth Engine with their attributes.

```js
var lots = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "id": "PlanId",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[152.6224, -30.0293], [152.6224, -30.0294], [152.6223, -30.0294], [152.6222, -30.0294], [152.6221, -30.0294], [152.6221, -30.0293], [152.622, -30.0292], [152.6219, -30.0292], [152.6218, ............- 30.0248]]]
        },
        "properties": {
            "PlanId": "777777777777777",
            "PlanName": "2023",
            "PlanStatusName":
            "Planning" }
    }, {
        "id": "PlanId",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[152.6858, -31.5103], [152.6857, -31.5103], [152.6856, -31.5103], [152.6855, -31.5103], [152.6854, -31.5103], [152.6853, -31.5105]
        ........... etc.1.5103], [152.6854, -31.5103], [152.6853, -31.5105]........ etc.
```

How can I take this script and convert it into something the Google Earth Engine JavaScript API will produce polygons with?

Comment: Please use a JSON pretty-printer to legibly format your content.

Answer (score 1):

You simply do:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(lots)
```